# How to fetch the last digit in the id of a textfield using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to retrieve ID of a textfield and find the last number in the ID.
I did this -

```
var div_id = parseInt($(row).find('input:text').first().attr('id').length-1);
```

But, this fetches me number of letters in the ID .
The ID's are in the form,

```
Ivrgroupzbase_grpzWelcomeNotes
Ivrgroupzbase_grpzWelcomeNotes1
Ivrgroupzbase_grpzWelcomeNotes2
Ivrgroupzbase_grpzWelcomeNotes3
```

How can I do this

Comment: It's a string, so.... [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Comment: I'm trying with substring

Comment: And what is the number of the first one?

Comment: You are subtracting one from the length. Where are you using substring?

Comment: "Ivrgroupzbase_grpzWelcomeNotes1".substr(-1,1)

Comment: @Zentoaku I get NaN with substr

Comment: Just add some verification: isNaN(parseInt("Ivrgroupzbase_grpzWelcomeNotes".substr(-1,1)))?0:parseInt("Ivrgroupzbase_grpzWelcomeNotes".substr(-1,1))

Comment: What happens when the number is greater than 9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better solution than in my comment, matches numbers at end no matter how many:

```
parseInt(("Ivrgroupzbase_grpzWelcomeNotes".match(/[0-9]+$/) || [0])[0])
0
parseInt(("Ivrgroupzbase_grpzWelcomeNotes123".match(/[0-9]+$/) || [0])[0])
123
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression:

```
div_id = $(row).find('input:text').first().attr('id').match(/\d+$/)
```

You won't get a number in the first because there isn't any.

Answer (score 0):

Slice would work well/easy.

```
var $element = $('#Ivrgroupzbase_grpzWelcomeNotes3');

console.log($element.attr('id').slice(-1));
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fomk9j2L/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
 var div_id = parseInt($(row).find('input:text').first().attr('id');
 if(div_id.match(/\d+$/)){
     last_number_in_id = div_id.substr(div_id.length-1);
 }else alert (div_id + "has no number");
```